# Activerecord, efficient way to find record from a comma separated string attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm working on a user management system in rails.

My user model has multiple emails:

```
email: string
additional_emails: string
```

Additional emails is a comma separated string, so "test@example.com,test2@example.com"

I use

```
User.find_by_email
```

to search a user by the primary email, but I'm looking for an efficient way to search for a user by `email` and also by `additional_emails`

At this moment I'm working on this. It works, but maybe there is a better way

```
User.where(email: email).or(User.where('additional_emails LIKE ?', "%#{email}%")).first
```

Comment: I suggest using another table for additional user emails. 
e.g user_adddiitional_emails with user_id, email columns.
Then you can validate and search emails easier.

Comment: If you want one more reason why a comma separated string is bad idea then consider that `,` is actually a legit character in an email address (with some limitations). Hello edge cases. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address

Comment: Building on what @MaksimP said, you could create an `AdditionalEmail` table with a belongs_to User association, and then could lookup additional emails by user.additional_emails.where(email: some_email@domain.com)